# Switch between recycler view and fragment when button clicked in activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a simple layout with recycler view and frame layout where I want to show a fragment. The idea is that I have a list of data displayed in recycler view -(where I inject cardview with imageView and textView) and frameLayout which is a container for my fragment. Once an item is clicked it should display a fragment with details. I know that's a better way is to have two fragments and change them, but since I only have one activity and two screens I want to have just one fragment.

Here's the layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="michael.com.ui.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#00000000"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

==

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    @BindView(R.id.list) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.container) FrameLayout container;
    @Inject Service service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setRecyclerView();

        TeamPresenter mPresenter = new TeamPresenter(service, this);
        mPresenter.getContacts();

    }

    private void setRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2));
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void showContacts(Response response) {

        ContactsAdapter mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(response.getContacts(),
                new ContactsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(Contacts item) {

                    initFragment(DetailsFragment.newInstance());

                    }
                });
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }


    private void initFragment(Fragment detailFragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, detailFragment, "TAG");
        transaction.addToBackStack("TAG");
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

I know I can probably setVisibility to INVISIBLE to RecyclerView when I init the fragment. But then how do I handle pressBack button from the Fragment to get back to the main screen?

Answer (score 2):

You Can Create a Interface that implements the Main Activity.

Create an Interface

```
public interface FragmentListener {

    public void listen();
}
```

Declare an Instance of Your Interface into your Fragment `onResume()` Method

```
public void onResume(){
FragmentListener listener= (FragmentListener ) getActivity();
listener.listen();

}
```

override listen Method in the Main Activity

```
@Override
public void listen(){
     recyclerView.setVisibility(GONE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int pos, boolean smoothScroll) method